# Only 1 popover at a time using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and the selector option?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I'm opening a bootstrap modal window that loads, via Ajax, a bunch of ".map-pin" images.  Clicking on the images should open popovers.  This much I have working:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '.map-pin',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return $(this).next('.popover_content').html();
    }
});
```

Now, however, I need only 1 popover to be open at a time.  And, it would be great if clicking on the body (and not on a popover) closed all open popovers.  This must work in Bootstrap 3.1.1.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit difficult, when we not see the whole setup, markup and so on - but here we go anyway :) First, why do you want to use the selector option? Seems a little backwards. I think you should initialize popovers for each `.map-pin` instead. Run this  after the HTML is injected via AJAX :

```
$('.map-pin').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return $(this).next('.popover_content').html();
    }
});
```

Then, to avoid multiple popovers visible at the same time :

```
$('.map-pin').on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $('.map-pin').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

And lastly, hide any visible popover, if you click on the body, and not on a `.map-pin` or the popover themselves :

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className!='map-pin' && 
        e.target.className!='popover' &&
        e.target.className!='popover-content') {
       $('.map-pin').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3W6AY/**